# How to call a Button from a different fragment (Java)?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, imageview, onclicklistener

I have two fragments: `Fragment1` and `Fragment2`. In `Fragment1` there is a button `button` and in `Fragment2` there is an ImageView `ImageView`. If the user clicks `button` in `Fragment1` he gets directed to `Fragment2`, where he can click `ImageView`. The function `function` for that is stored in `Fragment1`.

How can I use an `OnClickListener` on the `ImageView` of `Fragment2` in `Fragment1`, even though it isn't in the layout file of `Fragment1`?

Right now I get the error code:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.bottles.Fragment1.onClick(Fragment1.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it,if it is not in layout file.
Add that imageview to layout and call it with unique id.

For example id of the imageview is "imageview".

Do this in java file inside of,which extends your fragment:

```
Imageview imageview;
```

then in your onCreateView,call this:

```
imageview=view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

To make it as a  button,do this:

```
imageview.setOnclicklistner(new OnclickListner){//do what you want here.}
```